# BLE sends junk data on onLeScan

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Working on Bluetooth communication using https://github.com/GitGarage/BLEMingleDroid

While receiving data I am getting some junk Char appended to my real message, below is my code for sending and receiving message

AdvertiseData

```
        byte[] data = message.getBytes();
        ParcelUuid pu = ParcelUuid.fromString("0000" + asHex(message.substring(0,2).getBytes()) + "-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        AdvertiseData.Builder builder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
        builder.addServiceData(pu, data);
        builder.addServiceUuid(pu);
```

Receive Data

```
@Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice newDevice, final int newRssi,
                         final byte[] newScanRecord) {
 String message = new String(newScanRecord);
        TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String oldText = textViewToChange.getText().toString();
        String device = newDevice.getAddress();
        String rssi = "" + newRssi;

}
```

I am not sure for what reason this junk appended to my real message, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That's not junk data. The [scanRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback) is an array of bytes, so you can't just convert it to a String.

```
void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
```

The scanRecord often contains strings, like the advertised device name, but it also contains service uuids, and other data that needs to be parsed. You need to manually parse this data. The scanRecord will have a byte indicating the length, a byte indicating the data type, then the data. Additional length, type, value bytes can follow the first one. The type codes are listed in the [Generic Access Profile documentation](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile).